# Backing up an iPhone without the use of a cloud service or a computer

Tags: iphone, backup, external-disk

I will soon lead a lifestyle where I'll be required to travel a lot, and at the same time I've decided to ditch (or at least just phase out using) my computers (both Windows and Mac).

I will be using my iPhone from now on, for all things digital, so I'll move all my files from my computer to my phone.

That sounds all good in theory, but given I do not use any cloud services (nor do I plan to), how will I backup those files?

So far, I kept all my files on my computer. I'd just plug in an external HD and use either Time Machine (on Mac) or an encrypted VeraCrypt container (on Windows) to backup my files.

What can I do to backup the files on my iPhone, without a computer or a cloud service?

While, as of recently, iOS can mount an external flash drive, it makes no sense tranferring my files to an unencrypted drive just for the sake of backup. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but it can't mount an encrypted HD, does it?)

Can you think of any solutions to this problem?

Comment: iOS only supports backup to a computer running iTunes or to iCloud.

Comment: Without a computer or iCloud to backup to, what were you envisioning would accomplish this task?

Comment: but why no iCoud solution?  That works flawlessly and for little money you get a lot of storage space (iCloud). The requirement is internet to create the backups

Comment: Great timing to be leading a lifestyle where you're traveling a lot!

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for letting me know. This is final, right? No workarounds found yet?

Comment: @swisscodemen I wouldn't use a cloud service not owned/operated by me.

Comment: Yes.  Thus my question.  How do you see this solution coming together?  Plugging in a drive?  OK.  *Did you try it?*. What was your results?

Comment: @Allan I'm fine with the question, I can understand that users might hope that there is a 3rd party app (or a iOS feature unknown to them) able to backup to an attached drive.

Comment: @nohillside, not my point, but OK.

Answer (score 1):

iOS only supports backup to a computer running iTunes or to iCloud.

If your aim is to keep everything on servers you control yourself you might use an NextCloud installation (with disk encryption) and use the Files app (or native NextCloud apps) to manage your data. That way you at least won't use your data in case your phone gets lost or stolen.

Answer (score 0):

If you would never use a "**foreign**" cloud server, then try a Synology NAS Disk Station. There are many ways to backup data (photos, files, videos ...).

There are even Synology apps from the app store for iPhone and iPad (DS video, DS photo, DS audio, DS file...). A look at the Synology app would certainly be worthwhile.

So you have the backup (photos, files, music...) on your own hard disk and a redundant protection (raid systems possible) with you.

For more information, visit the synology website https://www.synology.com/en-global